# What does ば do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

What does ば do in this sentence? I am familiar with it as a conditional but it doesn't seem right here.

> 早朝と言っても人影がまばらにあって、露店の準備をしているホビット**もいれば**、僕と同じ冒険者のドワーフ達が徒党を組んで何か話し合っている。これからダンジョンへ向かうんだろう。

I interpreted the first sentence as

> If there were hobbits that were preparing stalls, then they would talk
>   to adventurers, like me, join their party, and then discuss something
>   together. After that they would head probably head towards the
>   dungeon.

But then this sentence followed after, so I don't think I interpreted the first sentence correctly.

> 僕もダンジョンへもぐる装備を身に付けて神様から逃げ出し...もとい部屋から出てきたから、**傍{はた}から見れば彼らと似ったり寄ったりかもしれない。**

Thanks.

Comment: What is 「どーワフ」?  「ドワーフ」?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「露店{ろてん}の準備{じゅんび}をしているホビットもいれ**ば**、～～～」

In this sentence, 「ば」 is used to express ***juxtaposition***.

Usually, one would expect it to be in the form of 「Aも～～ば、Bも～～だ/です/である」, but you are obviously not reading a very serious piece of writing and the author did not use the second 「も」.

***"there were a group of hobbits doing ~~ and a group of dwarfs doing ~~"***

> 「傍{はた}から見{み}れ**ば**～～～」

Here, 「ば」 expresses "conditional".

"***If/when*** seen from the outside"

Examples taken from [プログレッシブ和英中辞典's entry for 「ば」, section ￼￼2](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%81%B0):

> 「彼{かれ}はゴルフもやれ**ば**テニスもやる。」 "He plays not only golf but also tennis."
>
> 「彼には妻{つま}もあれ**ば**子{こ}もある。」 "He has a wife, and a child as well."