# What nuances do the も…ば…も structure carry?

Tags: nuances, syntax

In the book that I'm reading and a few other occasions, I saw the も…ば…も sentence structure.

For example:

> 俺には特殊な力もなければ秘められた才能もない。

I searched ば on jisho.org and it says that も…ば…も means "and". This is not very helpful because there are other constructs that also means "and". This, for example:

> 俺には特殊な力がなく秘められた才能もない。

Does the も…ば…も structure sound more literary/archaic/cool?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40420/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25895/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot find an explanation for a pattern like this on a dictionary. It's out of the scope of dictionaries. Instead, try articles like this (I just googled "も ば も"):

- [Learn JLPT N2 Grammar: も～ば～も (mo~ba~mo)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%82%82%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%B0%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%82-mobamo/)
- [JGram - も～ば～も [も～ば～も] (mo-ba-mo)](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=mo-ba-mo)

This pattern is not particularly literary, archaic, difficult nor poetic. Still, it's relatively uncommon in the most casual real conversations. You will find this pattern mainly in written sentences and fictional conversations.