# Uses of ば in this example

Tags: grammar

I am familiar with the conditional use of ば in sentences like 薬を飲めば良くなる。

But in the sentences below I am wondering if ば works differently, since to my understanding a conditional in this context doesn't make sense.

> 運ばれる料理に満足そうに舌鼓を打つエルフも**いれば**、テーブルをくっつけお祭り騒ぎのパルゥム達もいる。

or

> 獣の耳と尻尾を生やした獣人の女性が大胆な服装で客引きを**していれば**、それよりもっと過激な格好をしたアマゾネスの一行が、周囲の視線も気にせず談笑しながら闊歩している

Comment: Related: [What does ば do in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25892/43676), [What nuances do the も…ば…も structure carry?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52420/43676), [What does this ~ば mean, is this some irregular use of the conditional?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54371/43676)

Comment: @broccolifacemask, も・ば・も certainly applies to the top example. However, the bottom example lacks the も in the first clause, and the one in the second clause isn't in the correct location for the も・ば・も pattern to apply. Do we have any other threads that could answer the poster's question for the second example?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Then the first one aguijonazo cited...?

Comment: @broccolifacemask, thank you, but that one does include the も, as in もいれば、。。。 Meanwhile, the questioner's second example lacks that も, and instead we have をしていれば、。。。  Just based on my own reading of this second example, this _seems_ like another case where ば is being used to enumerate things, but I am not familiar enough with this construction without も to be able to explain it well.